# script to read information from other sites

Tags: scripting, scripting-language

a friend of mine wrote a script, which read information from other sites e.g. number of followers 3 ppl had and displayed them on his website. I was interested in doing such things. I searched for scripting and found out there are many scripting languages. How would I chose which one to learn? are they all the same? which one do u prefer to do my task? and finally any good reference you suggest?
where I stand now: im basically starting from zero in scripting but I know how to code C, C++, HTML...
Thanks=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sites you want to read from have an API for doing this (e.g. Twitter) then I would take a look at something like [Yahoo! Query Language](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/).

If they don't have an API then this Wikipedia article may be a good place to start: [Web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)

There's no specific language which is best for doing this kind of thing, it's down to what you prefer. I expect there are some C++ libraries out there for doing this.

Comment: thanks i looked at facebook, twitter queries. I dont have any work experience in scripts, which language do u advice me to start from?

Comment: @Syntax_Error If you fancy trying something new, how about Python and Beautiful Soup? http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/